# Elasticsearch get unique field count only once in a date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a case wherein I need to extract users(user_id) who appeared multiple times in a given period. I created an aggregation wherein I can extract and count the instances they appeared for a certain period but they should **not** be counted again on the next date or so, it should only appear once.

It's like counting unique user sign-up given a time period, you only need to count the first instance / date they appear. Date filters can be hourly, daily, weekly, monthly.

```
 user_id_1   2020-01-05
 user_id_1   2020-02-06
 user_id_1   2020-02-14
 user_id_2   2020-02-03
 user_id_2   2020-02-04
 user_id_3   2020-03-03
 user_id_1   2020-03-15
 user_id_2   2020-03-21
 user_id_3   2020-03-25
 user_id_3   2020-04-01
```

The expected output should be, get only counted once on the month they first show up. They shouldn't be counted again on other months

```
user_id_1 | 1 count | 2020-01-05
user_id_2 | 1 count | 2020-02-03
user_id_3 | 1 count | 2020-03-03
Total     | 3 counts|
```

Here is a sample code that I've come up with. It counts the instances of user_ids that appear on a given period.

```
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "result":{
         "date_range":{
            "field":"timestamp",
            "format":"yyyy-MM-dd",
            "ranges":[
               {
                  "from":"2020-01-01",
                  "to":"2020-03-31"
               }
            ]
         },
         "aggs":{
            "histogram":{
               "date_histogram":{
                  "field":"timestamp",
                  "calendar_interval":"1M",
                  "extended_bounds":{
                     "min":"2020-01-01",
                     "max":"2020-03-31"
                  },
                  "format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
               },
               "aggs":{
                  "user_sigups":{
                     "terms":{
                        "field":"user_id.keyword"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The sample result of the above query looks like this.

```
{
   "histogram":{
      "buckets":[
         {
            "key_as_string":"2020-01-01",
            "key":1577836800000,
            "doc_count":1925,
            "user_sigups":{
               "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
               "sum_other_doc_count":328,
               "buckets":[
                  {
                     "key":"2532456443539602",
                     "doc_count":505
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use cardinality aggregation to count unique items and min aggregation to get minimum date

Query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "result": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "2020-01-01",
            "to": "2020-03-31"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "histogram": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "date",
            "interval": "1M",
            "extended_bounds": {
              "min": "2020-01-01",
              "max": "2020-03-31"
            },
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "user_sigups": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "user_id.keyword"
              },
             "aggs": {
               "unique_count": {
                 "cardinality": {
                   "field": "user_id.keyword"
                 }
               },
               "min_date":{
                 "min": {
                   "field": "timestamp"
                 }
               }
             }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "result" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "2020-01-01-2020-03-31",
          "from" : 1.5778368E12,
          "from_as_string" : "2020-01-01",
          "to" : 1.5856128E12,
          "to_as_string" : "2020-03-31",
          "doc_count" : 9,
          "histogram" : {
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key_as_string" : "2020-01-01",
                "key" : 1577836800000,
                "doc_count" : 1,
                "user_sigups" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "user_id_1",
                      "doc_count" : 1,
                      "min_date" : {
                        "value" : 1.5781824E12,
                        "value_as_string" : "2020-01-05"
                      },
                      "unique_count" : {
                        "value" : 1
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "key_as_string" : "2020-02-01",
                "key" : 1580515200000,
                "doc_count" : 4,
                "user_sigups" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "user_id_1",
                      "doc_count" : 2,
                      "min_date" : {
                        "value" : 1.5809472E12,
                        "value_as_string" : "2020-02-06"
                      },
                      "unique_count" : {
                        "value" : 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key" : "user_id_2",
                      "doc_count" : 2,
                      "min_date" : {
                        "value" : 1.580688E12,
                        "value_as_string" : "2020-02-03"
                      },
                      "unique_count" : {
                        "value" : 1
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "key_as_string" : "2020-03-01",
                "key" : 1583020800000,
                "doc_count" : 4,
                "user_sigups" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "user_id_3",
                      "doc_count" : 2,
                      "min_date" : {
                        "value" : 1.5831936E12,
                        "value_as_string" : "2020-03-03"
                      },
                      "unique_count" : {
                        "value" : 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key" : "user_id_1",
                      "doc_count" : 1,
                      "min_date" : {
                        "value" : 1.5842304E12,
                        "value_as_string" : "2020-03-15"
                      },
                      "unique_count" : {
                        "value" : 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "key" : "user_id_2",
                      "doc_count" : 1,
                      "min_date" : {
                        "value" : 1.5847488E12,
                        "value_as_string" : "2020-03-21"
                      },
                      "unique_count" : {
                        "value" : 1
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Let me know how it works for you

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity of what the output should be. 

My end result should be like counting unique user sign-up given a time period. Once the user_id show up on a specific date, it should be not counted again. It that even possible?

Comment: I think my above code does the same. Can you run it and give me the document where it is failing to better understand the issue

Comment: Tried running the code the result was, user_id_1 was counted on Jan. once, then counted again on Feb. Where it should've been user_id_1 will only get counted on the month of Jan then it will never show up again on other months since it was counted on Jan.

Comment: You will have to handle this client side. There is no way to get  min date global and min date in interval , within that bucket for a term. So this check has to be at cliengt side

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is the only way. Thank you for the insight, @jaspreet

Comment: Glad could be of help